# how i can insert a data from mssql to mysql database when insert data in msssql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two databases

1. MS SQL Server (with the table `t1`)
2. MySQL Server (with the table `t2`)

I want to insert the data into table `t2` on MySQL Server when some data inserted into table `t1` on MS SQL Server.

I have already tried to create the linked server and use the trigger but it is not working.

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe these links can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874587/replicate-microsoft-sql-to-other-databases  http://fr.slideshare.net/thetaung/sql-server-replication-transactional-replication-from-mssql-200x-to-mysql-5x

Comment: Show your trigger code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert T-SQL to MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986404/convert-t-sql-to-mysql)

Comment: you can use replication MSSQL and myssql.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904447/replication-between-sql-server-and-mysql-server